# eclipse keyboard language change key not working

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

In the Eclipse IDE(Neon. 3 release 4.6.3) editor, sometimes(especially after I selected vertical region of code being edited) keyboard language change key(Korean to English, vice-versa) doesn't work.

So, I have been rebooting Eclipse to get the key work again. How may I be able to recover the key function without rerunning the Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

When you change text selection mode to vertical, you might have used the shortcut which is alt+shift+a. As a matter of fact, [(left)alt+shift changes input language](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) at the level of Window.

So, you have to use "(left)alt+shift"(without a) to reset keyboard input language back to your home language(not English). That way you can use the language key on your keyboard to toggle input language between home language and English.